# Does Picasa for Linux support RAW from a Canon 7D?

Tags: canon, raw, linux, picasa, canon-7d

I'm running Ubuntu (Lucid) and have installed Google Picasa using the Synaptic Package Manager. The current version of Picasa for Linux is 3.0.0 Build 57.4402.

Currently, it renders my RAW images as thin pink rectangles. Is there any way I can get Picasa to handle my RAW files? I know my RAW format is supported in the current Windows version.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I dunno, I think the pink rectangles are a perfectly valid artistic choice. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That behavior is pretty typical for Picasa when it doesn't support a given format correctly (older releases had similar behavior with Nikon NEF files, and new Canon RAW formats as they are released):

- [Why do NEF files have purple or pink bar?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Picasa/thread?tid=61513a1e87b54c38&hl=en)
- [Canon RAW files have a pink/magenta overlay](http://groups.google.com/group/google-labs-picasa-for-linux/browse_frm/thread/635286286b8c611b/8b9e3b9091929748?lnk=gst&q=pink#8b9e3b9091929748)

If the windows version is working for you, I'd suspect it's simply because the Linux release is quite out of date (the version you posted is the most recent release for Linux, as of the time I'm writing this). As chills42 mentioned, you might try running the most recent Windows release on Wine, or look into native alternatives like Rawstudio, Shotwell, or F-Spot.

Answer (score 3):

The Linux version is only a beta, and google seems to have discontinued updates.

It looks like some people in the [picasa for linux user group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-labs-picasa-for-linux/browse_thread/thread/37c9ff49041d2eb1) are having a better time using the [windows version](http://picasa.google.com/) installed through [wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: The version provided by Google also uses wine. There is no current native implementation for Linux yet. And there won't be for a long time...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it doesn't, based on the images, you could pre-process your images with something like [DCRaw](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) (which does support the 7D and about 400 other cameras) into either 8-bit or 16-bit images (depending on whether or not you want to keep the full 14-bits of info from your 7D).

With the `-T` option, DCRaw will generate a 16-bit TIFF with metadta. Otherwise I believe it makes 8-bit JPEGs.

[2]: http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/#faq DCRaw FAQ